# How to turn symbols into circle using scatterchart JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, symbols, scatter

I want to build Parisian subway, so I need to display all the stations as a circle with the correct color. Here is what I obtain : [All the stations displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPEYN.png). However, I want all the symbols to be circles but I can't find how to do it. Below is my code :

```
public static void setChartsAndLegend(Color color, ScatterChart<Number, Number> sc, int size) {
    String colorHex = "#"+Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB()).substring(2);
    String blackHex = "#"+Integer.toHexString(Color.BLACK.getRGB()).substring(2);
    int metroSize = 3*size;
    int hubSize = 4*size;
    String metroSizeString = String.valueOf(metroSize);
    String hubSizeToString = String.valueOf(hubSize);
    Set<Node> nodes = sc.lookupAll(".series" + 0);
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + colorHex + ";\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: " + metroSizeString + "px;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: " + metroSizeString + "px;");
    }
    nodes = sc.lookupAll(".series" + 1);
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        n.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + blackHex + ", white;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: " + hubSizeToString + "px;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: " + hubSizeToString + "px;");
    }
}
```

This is the function I use to display one line but when I want to display several lines, symbols are not circles anymore. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the default CSS style for `ScatterChart` symbols:

```css
.chart-symbol { /* solid circle */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
.default-color1.chart-symbol { /* solid square */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.default-color2.chart-symbol { /* solid diamond */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
    -fx-shape: "M5,0 L10,9 L5,18 L0,9 Z";
}
.default-color3.chart-symbol { /* cross */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_4;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-shape: "M2,0 L5,4 L8,0 L10,0 L10,2 L6,5 L10,8 L10,10 L8,10 L5,6 L2,10 L0,10 L0,8 L4,5 L0,2 L0,0 Z";
}
.default-color4.chart-symbol { /* solid triangle */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_5;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-shape: "M5,0 L10,8 L0,8 Z";
}
.default-color5.chart-symbol { /* hollow circle */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_6, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
.default-color6.chart-symbol { /* hollow square */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_7, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.default-color7.chart-symbol { /* hollow diamond */
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_8, white;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2.5;
    -fx-padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
    -fx-shape: "M5,0 L10,9 L5,18 L0,9 Z";
}
```

All you need to do is making all of them look like `.chart-symbol`:

```css
.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
.default-color1.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color2.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_3;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color3.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_4;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color4.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_5;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color5.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_6;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color6.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_7;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.default-color7.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: CHART_COLOR_8;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
```

If you want all of them to have the same color, you can give the color you like in `-fx-background-color`.

Comment: That's what I did by adding the style of `.chart-symbol` to all the nodes I want. However, it seems like Java doesn't remember the style of these nodes and so it creates new symbols. I don't know what to do, but thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: You should set `-fx-shape: null;` so it will not take the shape from the parent CSS file. I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh thank you so much it worked by adding `-fx-shape: null;`. Thank you again!